# React Navigation v6, prevent popping screen when navigating to a previous screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I'm using React Navigation v6 for React Native, consider the following navigation routes state:

```
1: {key: 'ClubScreen-PVQtJb1EkSv6q_wqPYpAi', name: 'ClubScreen', path: undefined, params: {…}}
2: {key: 'GameRoom538', name: 'GameRoom', path: undefined, params: {…}}
3: {key: 'GameRoom537', name: 'GameRoom', path: undefined, params: {…}}
```

when i call
`navigation.navigate({name:'GameRoom',key:'GameRoom538',params:{}})`
it goes to the second screen in routes array and the state of the screen is intact, no reload required, but it also pops 'GameRoom537', and if i try to call
`navigation.navigate({name:'GameRoom',key:'GameRoom537',params:{}})`
it will go to the screen but reload it(it will not find it in the stack so it will push a new screen) because it's not in the navigation state anymore.

Is there a way to switch between screens like this but keep them in memory?

Versions used:
"react-native": "0.71.8",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.3",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.4",
"@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.13",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.8.0",

I've tried using keys when calling 'navigate' and setting getId like this on my 'GameRoom' screen

```
<Stack.Screen
  ...
  getId={({ params: { id } }) => id}
/>
```

but the same behaviour still occurs.

**EDIT -- FOUND SOLUTION:**
Because i was using a stack navigator, going back a screen always popped the latest one from memory.
To fix this I've used a tab navigator just for the screens i wanted to keep in memory and i navigate between them using `TabActions.jumpTo`. I've also hidden the tab bar and the integration is seamless.

Comment: you may want to edit your title - react-native-navigation is a very different nav library

Comment: see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions#push - this should solve your issue

Comment: yep, title was a bit misleading, changed it

Comment: push will add a new screen indeed, but when i need to navigate to `GameRoom538` (that's already loaded and in memory) from the example i've given it will still pop `GameRoom537`, if instead i try to `StackActions.push('GameRoom', {id:538})` it will be a new screen and will still reload which is not what i want